# Laravel Livewire Anchor Tag Url Not Working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 8 with Livewire.
My Laravel Livewire application URL is like `http://localhost/myproject`.

My Laravel Livewire admin panel url is like `http://localhost/myproject/admin`.

I am fetching problem with anchor tag. When I change the page in pagination the View button URL in Livewire add **public** is automatically.

My View button code as below:

```
<a href="{{route('manage-product',$resdata->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
```

but, link is showing like `http://localhost/myproject/public/admin/manage-product/15`. That View button link in **public** is automatically added by Livewire.

How i can remove **public** from **url('/')** function?

I attached a screen shot, please check.
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Check the `APP_URL` in your `.env`, that's probably why.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to add entry point to your project in server settings. and in .env file you should write "APP_URL=http://localhost".

Answer (score 1):

Change the

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/myproject
```

Also you can check the official documentation to know more about URL
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).